# This condition will always return false since the types Light and Dark have no overlap

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was working on **[PuruVJ/macos-web](https://github.com/PuruVJ/macos-web)** with Visual Studio 2019 and got this error:

Error TS2367 (TS) This condition will always return `false` since the types `Light` and `Dark`.

I've tried using `else if` but that gave me the same error.

Code: https://github.com/MrHallway0/macos-web/commit/2fc6aa0beb8b2f1ff66b232ac38cf42b76920032#diff-beb41818bec1694e5b11a2705c90e118951c9d3214b9446dd06f22152943be4d.

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Questions need to stand on their own, preferably as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your file, on **Line 11**, you declare `DisplayMode` as a constant variable and set it equal to `Light`. This will prevent any changing the value to dark to test as a conditional statement.

```js
const DisplayMode = 'Light';
```

If this is the line that should tell whether it is light or dark mode, use a ternary like this:

```js
const darkModeActive = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches;
const DisplayMode = darkModeActive ? 'Dark' : 'Light';
```

The first line will check the user's system to see if they have dark mode currently enabled.